# git pull request into master didn't get all commits from the merging branch

Tags: git, merge

I got branch1 and I issued a pull request through git repo on the website, and the site says that there is no conflict between branch1 and master and merge can be done automatically, so I confirmed merge and it prompted as merge success. But then I noticed that none of the commits from the branch1 were actually got into master.

I also noticed that master has 3 simple commits to some readme.txt files that were not in branch1, but they are not conflicting with the branch1.

So, what do I do now to ensure all branch1 commits merged into master?

Comment: What review system do you use? How did you check that there are no commits on `master`? Did you do `git pull` before checking?

Comment: I didn't pull before checking. Let me check that.

Comment: Did you just did `git checkout`? Remember to use `git pull` after switching to master.

Comment: I definitely did git checkout on master

Comment: Please read my posts more carefully: I did ask about `git pull`.

Comment: I think I just made it worse, I did a revert on the pull request that I confirmed the first time, now I've got some more updates I did on branch1 and I am trying to do the pull request again, but now it says:  `Can’t automatically merge. Don’t worry, you can still create the pull request.` what I do now?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, the `git pull` command should be done before checking, I thought the `git checkout` would do that, but it didn't, so I would like to mark your suggestion as answer, please post your comment again as an answer so I can mark it as such, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comments in order to see merged commits in the local repository `git pull` must be done first.